# Android: SQLiteCursor/SimpleCursorAdapter in background

Tags: android, database, multithreading, background, adapter

My problem is related to Android. I have the following code (non-relevant parts omitted):

```
public class MyActivity extends ListActivity {
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        new UpdateTask().execute();
    }

    private class UpdateTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, ListAdapter> {
        protected ListAdapter doInBackground(Object... params) {
            SQLiteCursor cursor = db.getSomeData();
            startManagingCursor(cursor);
            SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, ..., cursor, ..., ...);
            return adapter;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(ListAdapter result) {
            listView.setAdapter(result);
        }
    }
 }
```

This causes a RuntimeException - "Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()" at the line where SimpleCursorAdapter is instantiated.

I understand why this is happening, I just don't know how to fix it (keeping this in a separate thread). I have found this thread:

http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/34d0069bb2de925e?fwc=2

But I don't really understand the reply. I have failed to google any
example involving SQLiteCursor and AsyncQueryHandler.

Could you guys please help? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like instantiating the `SimpleCursorAdapter` has to happen on the UI thread.  You could do that by having `doInBackground()` return `cursor` and setting up the adapter in `onPostExecute()`.

See [Painless Threading](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/05/painless-threading.html) if you haven't already.

Comment: You're right. But wouldn't that block the UI thread if the cursor returned like thousands of records?

Comment: I think the initial query is done once the cursor is returned, and the adapter won't stall even if it has lots of records.  

Now, [the Javadocs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html) reveal that the `SimpleCursorAdapter` constructor is deprecated in API Level 11 because of _requerying_ which will happen on the UI thread, when the underlying content broadcasts a change.
If you're developing against an earlier API, it looks like you have to either put up with requerying on the UI thread, or roll your own `ResourceCursorAdapter`.

Comment: I'm using API Level 7. I guess I will have to perform some tests to see how the SimpleCursorAdapter really behaves. But even if I find out it blocks the UI thread, I will probably have to leave it that way as I don't see any other option. Thank you, Robert.

Answer (score 0):

just put Looper.prepare();  at the top of the method that throws such an error